# Monero Not connecting to Daemon after upgrading to v0.13.0.3 on Windows 10

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I upgraded to v0.13.03 and when I start Monero the command prompt opens and closes ver quickly my wallet loads fine and shows my balance but my status is disconnected and the daemon is not connnected either. The log message is couldnt getting to 127.0.0.1 . Do I just have to wait for the database conversion? Or is there some fix for this? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A.  Yes, at first, you must let the database do its upgrades.  It actually could take an hour or two (hopefully nor more than that, but it depends).

B.  Make sure you're not only using a v0.13 daemon, but also a v0.13 wallet as well.  It sounds like you are, but just making sure.

Comment: I have been waiting actually longer than that. It have been maybe 7 or 8 hours plus. When I go to remote mode it shows synchronized and everything looks fine, but local node on dameon still stays disconnected.  appriciate your information though. Is there any way to know the progress of the database conversion?

Comment: and yeah the daemon and the wallet I downloaded the file from the site itself. The complete zip file.

Comment: Go to Settings > Log, type `status` and enter/return.  I bet you'll get the same message.  Hm.  May be a bug.

Comment: Okay, this happened to me too.  I had to open `monerod` manually. Must be a bug that'll be fixed in an upcoming point release...

Comment: Note: you _can_ open the `monerod` binary directly, and then `monero-wallet-gui` will behave as expected.